# Do we need to add a jVector tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

According to you, do we need to add a jVector tag to do reference to the [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) project?

jVector is broad and could concern javascript / HTML / python issues.

I added the [jvectormap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jvectormap) tag on the following question : [How to generate jVectorMap for United Kingdom (UK)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90783/how-to-generate-jvectormap-for-united-kingdom-uk)

Did I do well, or should it be removed/renamed?

Comment: Seems to be under the python tag, maybe create a synonym tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guidelines on creating tags are described **[here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)**.

The rule of thumb that I use on when to create a new tag is whether it is likely to be used a few hundred times over the next few years.

Your new tag would seem to fulfil this criterion, and I encourage you to create a tag wiki for it.